# OpenbravoErp performance testing

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, openbravo

I only want to record and playback login page of openbravo,
problem is i don't know it is successfully playing back or not using VU(Jmeter).

[image]

How to know Virtual User(VU) is performing same like a real user ?

After @Dmitri T help i got following things

[image]

Why HTML is not parsed/how can parse it ?
I want Jmeter to mimic like real application ?

This might help you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're half-way from your goal, all you need to do is:

- Switch to "Response Data" tab
- Select "HTML" or "HTML (download resources)" from the drop-down in order to see the rendered response

[image: View Results Tree example]

In order to make your test even more realistic:

1. Make sure that all your HTTP Requests have "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" box checked and you're using "concurrent pool" with the size of 3-5 threads as this is how real browsers act. The best way to configure it for all the samplers without having to change each request is using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://blazemeter.com/blog/http-request-defaults)

   [image: HTTP Request defaults]
2. Real browsers download embedded resources, like scripts, styles and images, but they do it **only once**. On subsequent requests these resources are being returned from the browser cache. In order to simulate this behavior you need to add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager).

Comment: Something is wrong with your response, HTML is malformed hence it cannot be rendered. Try saving it into a file and open it with browser

Comment: Tried by using save responses to a file. 1st file gives file not found